# Pseudoelement :after changes size of parent div component

Tags: html, css, sass, pseudo-element

I’m trying to create gallery like this:

```css
 .gallery-item{
     overflow: hidden;}

     .gallery-item:after{
      content: "text ....";
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      transform: translate(20px, -30px);}

     img{
      width: 100%}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 gallery-item">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c2/0b/2a/c20b2a893ad6d1d29764416207c8b885--sahara-marocain-morocco.jpg">
     </div> 
     <div class="col-md-4 gallery-item">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c2/0b/2a/c20b2a893ad6d1d29764416207c8b885--sahara-marocain-morocco.jpg">
     </div> 
     <div class="col-md-4 gallery-item">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c2/0b/2a/c20b2a893ad6d1d29764416207c8b885--sahara-marocain-morocco.jpg">
     </div> 
    </div>
```

I've create :after with some text, but this element changes size of parent .gallery-item. I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: Did you try `position:absolute` instead of `relative` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `position: absolute;`on the pseudo element ::after so it won't impact the parent.

```
.gallery-item
  overflow: hidden
  &:after
    content: "Content..."
    position: absolute;
    top: XXXX;
    left: XXXX;
    display: block
    transform: translate(20px, -30px)
```